# How can I repair a chip in an acrylic shower pan?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, shower

It's new but since it was layed out first when building the bathroom, workers came in and out being careless around it. Any way to repair, and is it harmful? The shower pan I think is arcylic.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damage on the shower pan shows a black base material. I'm assuming that is steel. I have repaired enameled steel tubs using epoxy enamel repair. I applied it in layers to get good curing and sanded and polished the top coat. In some cases sanding individual layers was necessary so that the areas within the repair did not build up to high. I also prepped the edges of the chipped area with a grinder to give a good clean oval to the damaged section.

Comment: I saw it was metal, not sure if steel. Is it not merely a cosmetic damage? The white is arcylic but it's bottom side is metal. I was just thinking of covering it up if it's harmless to integrity of the pan. Otherwise I may opt to "unearth" and replace it.

Comment: Also are you describing a restoration  of the enemal not just the metal? Is the epoxy the filling for it? I'm pretty new at this, is there a step by step if it's easy.

Comment: First, you have a porcelain on steel shower base. (Many steel tubs used to be porcelain on cast iron but they were too heavy and steel worked very well.) Acrylic would not chip and I've never known it to be molded over steel....The first time I tried this kind of repair I was doing it for hire in a $700,000 home. I was quite nervous. And in addition to making the repair using white Epoxy, I had to figure out how to make the color match because the tub was not absolute White. But that's another story.....You can purchase repair epoxy paint at any hardware store. You need a small bottle (about t

Comment: The brand is duravit shower tray, i remembered reading somewhere it's arcylic. But you may be right. So all I need is epoxy paint, and just fill it in the gap till it sets?

Comment: Try that first. Being an epoxy paint it should be able to adhere well to the acrylic. The only other option would be to use a two-part epoxy. The problem with that is that it would not stay in place on a vertical surface.

Comment: Hi again, I found something called epoxy putty that's made for bathrooms, would that be as good as epoxy paint? I also already have epoxy glue but I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: Hi, Altoban. Read the label to see if it is meant for chips like yours or some other type of repair. The important thing is to try something and not make this project seem bigger than it is ...
If you couldn't find Epoxy paint try asking a store associate to help you find it. It should be in the paint section or possibly in the appliance parts section ... Whatever you use the closer shoe repair comes to matching the acrylic finish, the list noticeable it will be.

Comment: ** not "shoe" ... "your"  :>)